# Angular 2 interpolation vs property binding

Tags: angularjs, angular

I know from multiple blogs and some questions here in stackoverflow that in Angular 1 ng-bind has better performance than {{ }} interpolation because of the way the $digest process works.

Angular 2 has changed the way it does data-binding and I want to know if there is any test on the subject. Specifically if this

```
<h1 [innerText]="obj.name"></h1>
```

is still better than this

```
<h1> {{ obj.name }} </h1>
```

Comment: `innerText` can't be better for simple reason, [it isn't standardized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText). And I guess that binding `textContent` will give you problems with Universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `getTitle()` method as example. `checkBinding` is debug mode check, can be ignored.

Attribute binding calls `sanitize` and `el.setAttribute`:

```
  var currVal_0 = self.context.getTitle();
  if (jit_checkBinding34(throwOnChange,self._expr_0,currVal_0)) {
    self.renderer.setElementAttribute(self._el_0,'innerHTML',((self.viewUtils.sanitizer.sanitize(jit_SecurityContext36.HTML,currVal_0) == null)? null: self.viewUtils.sanitizer.sanitize(jit_SecurityContext36.HTML,currVal_0).toString()));
    self._expr_0 = currVal_0;
  }
```

Interpolation, calls `el.textContent = value;`:

```
  var currVal_0 = jit_interpolate36(1,'',self.context.getTitle(),'');
  if (jit_checkBinding34(throwOnChange,self._expr_0,currVal_0)) {
    self.renderer.setText(self._text_1,currVal_0);
    self._expr_0 = currVal_0;
  }
```

The only difference is using `sanitize`, you can check html_sanitizer.ts source code to see that is does some complicated stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**Interpolation:** *It represents as {{}}. it may be concatenate two string ,calculate value and display value.*

**Property Binding:** *It represents as [].It is mainly used for non-concatenate string like variable.*

Comment: can you provide some example

Comment: Interpolation is a special syntax that Angular converts into a property binding. 

Interpolation is just a convenient alternative to property binding. 

In some cases like when we need to concatenate strings we have to use interpolation instead of property binding as shown in the example below.
<img src='http://www.pragimtech.com/{{imagePath}}' />

When setting an element property to a non-string data value, you must use property binding. In the following example, we are disabling a button by binding to the boolean property isDisabled.
<button [disabled]='isDisabled'>Click me</button>

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation is a convenient alternative for property binding in many cases.

In fact, Angular 2 translates those interpolations into the corresponding property bindings before rendering the view.

In Angular 2, I think there is no technical reason to prefer one form to the other. You should be choosing the form that feels most natural for the task.